# Multiple replacement in entire data frame in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame with 12 column and have to make multiple replacements. This is what I am doing to make each replacement. Is there a better way of making multiple replacements?

```
clean_df2<- map_df(clean_df1, ~ gsub("None", "-", .x))
```

Comment: Try with `clean_df1[clean_df1=='None']<-'-'`

Comment: Or `clean_df2<-clean_df1` and `clean_df2[clean_df2=='None']<-'-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also work:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
clean_df2 <- clean_df1 %>% mutate(across(everything(),~gsub("None", "-", .)))
```